# Google Search Console API returns responseAggregationType byPage

Tags: google-search-console, google-search-api

I have read-only access to a few domains on Google Search Console and I am using the GSC API to scrape their data. For most of them it works just fine, but for a few of them my query returns:

```
   {
   "responseAggregationType": "byPage"
   }
```

I read [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7576553) that this field can be configured in the request, but I didn't add any setting of that sort.
So why does it return the aggregation? How can I get "normal" results?

For reference, this is the JSON I am sending:

```
{
  "startDate": "2023-05-01",
  "endDate": "2023-05-31",
  "dimensions": [
    "QUERY",
    "PAGE"
  ]
}
```